# Disabling individual Sphinx warning messages

Tags: python-sphinx, toctree

I have many `.rst` files in my Sphinx tree which are intentionally excluded from any index tree. I get warnings like

```
 /filename.rst:: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree
```

How can I suppress specific warnings in Sphinx?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

1. Are there .rst files in your Sphinx project whose content you don't want in the output?

   Use the `exclude_patterns` configuration variable. No output (and no warning messages) will be generated for files matching the specified patterns. See http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-exclude_patterns.
2. Are there .rst files in your Sphinx project that are not part of any toctree but whose content should be in the output?

   Add `:orphan:` at the top of each .rst file to suppress the warning message. See http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/field-lists.html#file-wide-metadata

you can also use https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-suppress_warnings