# WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree for included file

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, toctree

I'm getting the warning:

```
WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree
```

for files that exist in the document because they've been explicitly included.  So I have the index file:

```
.. toctree::
    :maxdepth: 2

   pages/0010-foo
   pages/0020-bar
```

In the file 0020-bar.rst, I'm specifically including a number of other files, as in:

```
.. contents:: :local:

.. include:: /pages/reference-architecture/technical-considerations/0070-baz.rst
```

But when I build the project, I still get a warning that 0070-baz.rst isn't in any toctree, as in:

```
/home/nick/Documents/myProject/docs/pages/reference-architecture/technical-considerations/0070-baz.rst:: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree
```

The weird thing is that I can see the content in the output. Is this normal?  Does this warning always appear for files that are explicitly included rather than included via toctree?

Comment: AFAIK, every .rst file that is not explicitly included in a toctree is regarded as "stray" by Sphinx and a warning message is emitted. See also this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13109215/407651.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Sphinx will complain about this whether the file is included or not.

However, you can specifically exclude files by using the [exclude_patterns](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-exclude_patterns) config value.

So for your case you might try to change Sphinx's `conf.py` file with something like:

```
exclude_patterns = ['pages/reference-architecture', 'some/other/file.txt']
```

You can exclude individual files, directories, or use file globbing patterns to match groups of files this way.

**EDIT:** See: [Joakim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40725923/134391) for another option that was added after this answer was created.

Answer (score 77):

If you only want to `..include::` a document in another document, without having it appear in any `toctree`.

**Add `:orphan:` to the top of your document to get rid of the warning.**

This is a *File-wide metadata* option.  Read more from the [Sphinx documentation](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/field-lists.html#file-wide-metadata).

Comment: Also, see `:hidden:` option for `toctree`.

Answer (score 7):

I had a situation where I couldn't edit the documents I wanted to be brought in as a git submodule. The documents already had their own structure including TOC page written in Markdown and I did want them to be processed by sphinx for consistency of formatting.

What I found I could do is specify a hidden toctree to make toctree aware of the documents, but not clutter up the toctree or add a bunch of errors to my sphinx build output.

```
* :doc:`Additional Book <external/index>`

.. toctree::
   :hidden:

   external/documentA.md
   external/documentB.md
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a good answer in a few cases. Our use case was using a generated file that we didn't want to manually inject the `:orphan:` tag at the top.

Comment: I like this answer as it also help me to track which external docs are referenced in the current doc.

Answer (score 3):

Indentation worked:

```
  toctree::   
   :maxdepth: 2
       hello <h.rst>
       abc <your.rst>
```

Comment: The indentation you're showing is by no means required, however, an empty row between `:maxdepth: 2` and the next row is. It also could/should be simply `h` (filename minus rst), unless there is a specific reason you want to override the title of document.

Answer (score 0):

in my case i was including a readme.MD file, but it by default accepts only .md file with myst extension. when i changed the file format, it did not say anymore