# Importing Docstrings from Python modules using Sphinx and autodoc

Tags: documentation, python-sphinx

My project has the following structure.

```
Main_Folder:
 |---- .venv_folder
 |---- Documentation:
         |------ source
                   |------ index.rst,conf.py, Module_1.rst, Module_2.rst
         |------ build             
 |---- Modules:
         |------ Module_1
         |------ Module_2
```

In Module_1 and Module_2, I have some scripts with docstrings I want to show, in a html type of view.

In the source folder, I have

-> index.rst, with:

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   Module_1
   Module_2
```

-> conf.py, with:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../Modules'))
```

`os.path.abspath('../..')` returns `~/Main_Folder`

So, I've added the directory where my modules reside to sys.path.

In Module_1.rst and Module_2.rst, I have almost the same:

```
Module_1
===========

.. automodule:: Module_1
   :members:
```

When I run `sphinx-build -b html source build`, after having activated the venv, I get the following:

WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'Module_1'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'Modules'
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'Module_2'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'Modules'

How do I make sphinx to detect the modules?

Comment: This error is unrelated to finding modules. It has to do with having `common/doc_parsing` in one of your `toctree`s.

Comment: @StevePiercy I've changed the question. Maybe it's improved...

Comment: @mzjn I've edited the question. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ups, I just found the answer to my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62340756/sphinx-doesnt-find-the-modules-from-a-specific-directory?rq=1