# Sphinx suppress specific warnings?

Tags: python-sphinx, doxygen

In building my documentation I'm running into a lot of warning messages such as the following:

`/home/X/Y/src/core/include/math/bigintntl/transformntl.h:92: warning: documented empty return type of NTL::NumberTheoreticTransformNtl::ForwardTransformToBitReverseInPlace.` I'd like to turn off the specific warnings related to X is not documented. How might I go about doing so? I'm building the documentation of a rather large library, and until we have time to go back and update the docs, this just adds a lot of noise to our builds.

The documenting line:

```
  /**
   * In-place forward transform in the ring Z_q[X]/(X^n+1) with prime q and
   * power-of-two n s.t. 2n|q-1. Bit reversing indexes. [Algorithm 1 in
   * https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/504.pdf]
   *
   * @param &rootOfUnityTable is the table with the n-th root of unity powers in
   * bit reverse order.
   * @param &element[in,out] is the input/output of the transform of type VecType and length n.
   * @return none
   */
  void ForwardTransformToBitReverseInPlace(
      const VecType& rootOfUnityTable, VecType* element);
```

from [OpenFHE library](https://github.com/openfheorg/openfhe-temp/blob/documentation/src/core/include/math/bigintntl/transformntl.h#L101)

and the `.rst` file looks like the following (`autodoxygenindex` is a Breathe directive: https://breathe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/directives.html#autodoxygenindex):

```
Core Math Big Int NTL Documentation
=========================================

.. autodoxygenindex::
   :project: core_math_bigintntl
```

while the `conf.py` file is [here](https://github.com/openfheorg/openfhe-temp/blob/documentation/docs/conf.py).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. How are you documenting that missing member? It's hard to give a solution looking just at the warning.

Comment: I'm just looking to suppress the warning, not fix the documentation? Sorry, I must be misunderstanding what you mean

Comment: My question: how are you documenting the line that issues the warning? Your question doesn't have an example of the `.rst`.

Comment: Yes, I do use Breathe!

Comment: I haven't tried Doxygen and Breathe, but [try disabling the warnings individually on the Sphinx level](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-suppress_warnings) there are also [these options to suppress warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13109215) that I think work on a file level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue for me was that `breathe` was [regenerating the documentation](https://github.com/michaeljones/breathe/issues/826) because I was using a specific command. Unfortunately, this regeneration seemed to ignore the `Doxyfile` that was coming in. So, I had to manually pass in the relevant variables via `breathe_doxygen_config_options` [See breathe config-values](https://breathe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/directives.html#config-values)